# Pandas dataframe with time index and freq with multiplier

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a time series as index.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand

df = pd.DataFrame(rand(100000), index=None, columns=['a'])
df['time'] = pd.date_range('2020-01-01 12:30:15',
                           periods=len(df['a']), freq='ms')
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.plot()
```

When I put a multiplier on the frequency, it becomes extremely slow to plot `df2`, even if it has less elements than `df`. **EDIT 1:** It actually crashed my Python kernel, and my laptop almost ran out of RAM

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(rand(50000), index=None, columns=['a'])
df2['time'] = pd.date_range('2020-01-01 12:30:15',
                            periods=len(df2['a']), freq='2.5ms')
df2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df2.plot()
```

I was wondering if this behavior is normal

Thanks

**EDIT 2:** Versions of packages

- Python 3.9.3-1
- Pandas 1.2.3-1
- Numpy  1.20.1-1
- Matplotlib 3.4.1-2

**EDIT 3:** It works when plotting directly with matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax1.plot(df2);
```

Comment: I tried setting the `freq='2500us'` but it is nowhere as fast as with `df`

Comment: setting `df.index.freq='2500U'` does not have any effect on performance. However, the correct frequency info is displayed after typing `df2.index`

Comment: This is weird. You're right. Setting the freq to `2500U` (or `2.5ms`) the `df.plot()` fails (Jupyter kernel died). You may file an issue on pandas github https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas if there isn't yet.

Comment: I was also running on a jupyter kernel. I tried in the iPython console of spyder and it was the same. Reducing the size of `df2` to 10000 works. But I believe it should be able to handle the 100k points the same way it does with `df`, regardless of the value of `freq`